# Social sharing in Winjs application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm trying to add social sharing funtionallity (facebook, mail, etc) to my winjs application, but can't find the built in functionallity for it.

In a C#/ VB app, there is [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but I can't find it for winjs. It should be possible since winjs can access phone functionallity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the `DataTransferManager` for the current view first and add a listener to `datarequested` event. When this event triggers you can specify what data you want to share.

```
var dataTransferManager =
        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
dataTransferManager.addEventListener("datarequested", dataRequested);
...
function dataRequested(e) {
    var request = e.request;
    request.data.properties.title = 'a title';
    request.data.setText('Some text');
};
```

More on this sample [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datarequest.aspx)

To show the share functionality from anywhere in your app just add a handler for the click event to an element and show the UI.

```
document.getElementById("share").addEventListener("click", function () {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.showShareUI();
}, false);
```

All info you need to share other things, like HTML can be found at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link! What helped me most where the code samples form " http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84/ ".

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to use share contract, in case you are going for WinRT app.Since charms bar is not present you may need to do the coding

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.showShareUI();

function launchShare() {
    var shareButton = document.createElement("button");
    shareButton.setAttribute("id", "showShareButton");
    shareButton.innerText = "Click to share!";
    shareButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.showShareUI();
    });
    document.body.appendChild(shareButton);
}
```

Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh464923.aspx